# web service proxy setting

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, webservice-client

In c# 4.0, I have a web service called ManufacturerContactDetails. I am calling that web service from a windows app using the following:

```
var ws = new ManufacturerContactDetailsWebServiceSoapClient();
ContactDetails cd = ws.GetContactDetails("Google");
```

However, I would like to set the web proxy server that the soap client uses. I've had a look for a ws.Proxy property but it doesn't exist. I don't want to use the one from internet explorer.

How do I set the web proxy server to use?

Comment: What type does `ManufacturerContactDetailsWebServiceSoapClient` derives from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create the app config file containing the following

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True" bypassonlocal="True"/>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

More info here http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/porint/archive/2007/08/14/Configuring-a-proxy_2D00_server-for-WCF.aspx

Bye

Answer (score 9):

If this is a WCF client there is no Proxy property. You could try this instead:

```
var proxy = new WebProxy("proxy.foo.com", true);
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;
```

and then do the call:

```
using (var ws = new ManufacturerContactDetailsWebServiceSoapClient())
{
    var cd = ws.GetContactDetails("Google");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your app.config or web.config:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true">
    <proxy proxyaddress="http://111.222.333.444:80"/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Worked great. For pushing traffic through Fiddler, here's the line we used:

`<proxy proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888"/>`

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to app.config file.

```
<system.net> 
    <defaultProxy enabled="false" useDefaultCredentials="false"> 
        <proxy/> 
    </defaultProxy> 
</system.net>
```

Add proxy in the proxy tag.
Use the default proxy tag in the system.net setting in the app.config.