# Visual Studio - C# Script Task Error (SSIS)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, soap, ssis

I am wondering if anyone has encountered this same error, and if so, can point me in the right direction to try and fix it. The error reads:

Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key.

It seems like this error can stem from many different things.

I am trying to send data that is read from a CSV file to a SOAP web service. Below is the code I am using in the script task:

```
BasicHttpBinding CostCenterSoap = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://example.com/services/CostCenter.asmx");
CostCenterSoapClient client = new CostCenterSoapClient(CostCenterSoap, remoteAddress);

CostCenterProperties[] costcenters = new CostCenterProperties[list.Count];

for (var c = 1; c < list.Count; c++) {
  costcenters[c] = new CostCenterProperties
  {
    InteropID = list[c].CostCenter,
    CompanyInteropID = companyInteropID,
    Name = list[c].CostCenter,
    Description = list[c].CostCenter
  };

  try
  {
      client.Save(CostCenters: costcenters, SharedSecret: sharedSecret);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      errorList.Add(e.Message);
      MessageBox.Show("Errors from adding cost center: " + e.Message);
  }
}
```

What is even more confusing is that this same logic works perfectly fine for another web service in another script task. When using SoapUI to test, I can pass data to the web service just fine, so the issue must be reside with my script.

Screenshot of error from the StackTrace:

[image: Added screenshot of error.]

Here is my app.config file that is part of my script task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy usesystemdefault="True" bypassonlocal="True"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CostCenterSoap">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://www.example.com/services/CostCenter.asmx"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CostCenterSoap"
      contract="CostCenterService.CostCenterSoap" name="CostCenterSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have the StackTrace?  I can't tell where the 'key' is occurring in the code.

Comment: The StackTrace did not show anything (it was empty). I viewed it by going to: Debug > Windows > Call Stack.

Comment: No.  Instead of e.Message use e.StackTrace.

Comment: Got it. I posted a screenshot of the error message above.

Comment: You are missing the proxy server.  See following : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205270/web-service-proxy-setting

Comment: Thank you. I tried adding a few things, but still no luck. I have added the code from the app.config file above.

Comment: I would start by looking at the config file for the application that is working.  Either the proxy is incorrect in the config file or the proxy server isn't running.  I'm not sure but I suspect that default credentials would require a  Group Policy setting.  You may want to talk to your MIS people.  If you are trying to connect to a different PC (server) the PC need to be in the same group.  In a corporate network an admin must set up these credentials.

Comment: Thank you sir! Much appreciated! I'll chat with them; I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I checked with them today, and they told me there is no proxy server set up and that it is not needed to accomplish this.

Comment: These StackTraces are sometimes hard to really understand.  It looks like the Save() method is causing the error.  I would try to commenting out the code in the try/catch and see if error goes away.  If it does then we will know the Save() is the real root cause.